# SELECT middle part of a String if it exists. Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i've got a problem with transferring "real-World" data into my schema. 
It's actually a "project" for my Database course and they gave us ab table with dog race results. This Table has a column which contains the name of the Dog (which itself consists of the actuall name and the name of the breeder) and informations about the Birthcountry, actual living Country and the birth year.
Example filed are "Lillycette [AU 2012]" or "Black Bear Lee [AU/AU 2013]" or "Lemon Ralph [IE/UK 1998]".
I've managed it to get out the first word and save it in the right column with split_part like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblHund (rufname)
SELECT
    split_part(name, ' ', 1) AS rufname,
FROM tblimport;
```

tblimport is a table where I dumped the data from the csv file.
That works just as it should. 
Accessing the second part of the Name with this fails because sometimes there isn't a second part and sometimes times there second part consists of two words.

And this is the where iam stuck right now. 
I tried it with substring and regular expressions:

```
INSERT INTO tblZwinger (Name)
SELECT
    substring(vatertier from E'[^ ]*\\ ( +)$')AS Name
FROM tblimport
WHERE substring(vatertier from E'[^ ]*\\ ( +)$') != '';
```

The above code is executed without errors but actually does nothing because the SELECT statement just give empty strings back.

It took me more then 3h to understand a bit of this regular Expressions but I still feel pretty stupid when I look at them.

Is there any other way of doing this. If so just give me a hint.
If not what is wrong with my expression above?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use atom `.`, which matches any single character inside capturing group:

```
E'[^ ]*\\ (.+)$'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  tblimport.*,
  ti.parts[1] as f1,  
  ti.parts[2] as f2, -- It should be the "middle part"  
  ti.parts[3] as f3  
FROM
  tblimport,
  regexp_matches(tblimport.vatertier, '([^\s]+)\s*(.*)\s+\[(.*)\]') as ti(parts)
WHERE
  nullif(ti.parts[2], '') is not null
```

Something like above.